# Do we need to change 'and' to 'or' when the affirmative sentence is modified to negative or interrogative?

Tags: sentence-construction

A grammar rule has been taught in our school, in which when we modify an affirmative sentence to a negative or interrogative one, we should change 'and' to 'or'.

For example:

> 1. Eat **and** drink in the metro.
> 2. Don't eat **or** drink in the metro.
> 3. He **and** I are playing football.
> 4. He **or** I aren't playing football.

But I also saw some sentences in which 'and' should not change to 'or' when the sentences are modified to negative/interrogative.

For example,

> 5. You know French and English.
> 6. Do you know French and English?
> 7. Do you know French or English?
> 8. You don't know French and English. // This one seems not correct.
> 9. I don't know French or English.

There should be more, but I can not dig out all of them. Appreciate if anyone could provide more here.

So, are there any rules of thumb for this?

Comment: Can you please provide these other sentences you've seen? That would be very helpful, because it's hard to picture without your providing more info. Also, #4 is grammatically incorrect (***Neither he nor I is playing football***), so I'm not sure if you're understanding the rule well.

Comment: @Ringo, I just updated my question. I might not get all good examples for this indeed as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having made some research with the question [“Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like them.” how to say?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148497/bread-rice-and-porridge-i-dont-like-them-how-to-say) find the summary of the results below.

First of all, if you are looking for a really *clean* way to express *"Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like them (all)."* in *one coherent clause* (not just sentence or a clause with additional backreferences) then there is **only one way** known to me:

> I like **neither** bread **nor** rice **nor** porridge.

I admit though that *neither ... nor ... (nor ...)* sounds a bit too repelling if you don't intend to emphasize the negation of each item in particular. So, the next less repelling but *clean* way is to use the enumeration of all items and to refer to it, e.g. with a pronoun, *all*, or *following*:

> Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like **them** (all).
>    Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like (any of) **them**.
>    I don't like (any of) **the following food items**: bread, rice and porridge.

If you are looking for other, shorter, and more colloquial ways then the good news is: there are such ways; but the bad news is: they are ambiguous and therefore dependent on the context and the goodwill of the listener.

1) The *or*-way

> I don't like bread, rice, **or** porridge.

This way has been said to me to be the conventional way. But technically spoken this way is not quite correct because *bread, rice, **or** porridge* refers to **at least one** from the set `{ bread, rice, porridge }`. So, technically spoken it **could** have each of the following meanings:

> I don't like bread, but I like rice, and I like porridge.
>   I don't like rice, and I don't like rice but I like porridge.
>   I don't like porridge, and ...
>   ...

As the listener does not assume the speaker would let him guessing the specific meaning it's only a **pragmatic** consequence to interpret *"I don't like bread, rice, **or** porridge."* as

> I don't like bread. I don't like rice. And I don't like porridge.

2)
So, why not saying

> I don't like bread, rice, **and** porridge.

*Some* native speakers say this sentence would mean that I don't like bread, rice, **and** porridge **(mixed) together** though I might like bread, I might like rice, and I might like porridge. *Other* native speakers point out that in the context of *bread*, *rice*, and *porridge* there is no such mix of ingredients, so it would be perfectly understood as *"I don't like bread, I don't like rice, and I don't like porridge"*.

Two examples to show the difference:

> I don't like peanut butter and jelly.

would be understood as *"I don't like the combination of peanut butter and jelly"*. Whereas

> I don't like Fords, Audis, and Hondas.

would always be understood as *"I don't like Fords, I don't like Audis, and I don't like Hondas"* as you cannot mix cars together.

---

Coming back to your example, the negation of *"You know French and English."* could be both

> You don't know French and English.
>   You don't know French or English.

Though, myself, I prefer the clean form in this case:

> You know neither French nor English.

Comment: I would say "Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like **any of** them." For some reason the negation makes me want to use "any of" instead of "all of" because I would also say "Honey, syrup and sugar - I like **all of** them."

Comment: @ColleenV Thx for the advice! I compared it to the usage of other native speakers - they are absolutely in sync. I failed to notice this important detail from the beginning. Hence I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that this is incorrect. `And` and `or` convey different meanings, and so either can be correct depending on what you want to express.

For example, it makes perfect sense to say

> Don't eat **and** drink in the metro.

But this implies that you are not supposed to eat and drink at the same time, where

> Don't eat **or** drink in the metro.

prohibits you from doing either of those actions.

Comment: How about this pair *"I like bread , rice and porridge." vs "I don't like bread , rice or porridge."* ?

Comment: @dan If your negation should mean that you don't like at least *one of them* then your answer could be *"Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like one of them"* or *"I don't like at least one of bread, rice and porridge."* or *"I don't like bread, or I don't like rice or porridge but you have to guess which one!"* If your negation should mean that you don't like *all of them* then your answer could be *"I (don't) like neither bread nor rice nor porridge."*

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet, the sentence "I like bread , rice and porridge." means you like all of them, so the negation should mean you don't like all of them. In this case, should we put "I don't like bread , rice or porridge?"

Comment: @dan No, *"I don't like bread, rice or porridge"* means you don't like *at least one of them* but you're not saying which - so, you're letting your reader guessing. If you mean you don't like *all of them* you need to say *"I like **neither** bread **nor** rice **nor** porridge."* https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/neither-nor-nor?q=neither...nor+%28...nor%29

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet, "I like neither bread nor rice nor porridge." looks clumsy. Not sure if there is a better way to address it.

Comment: @dan I agree that looks a bit clumsy if the emphasis of the negation is not intended. Watch what answers we will get to this question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148497/bread-rice-and-porridge-i-dont-like-them-how-to-say

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet, Thanks for trying hard to get this clear!!! So, as a conclusion, it seems that there indeed is a rule for this. When we change "I like bread , rice and porridge." to "I don't like bread , rice or porridge," we should change *and* to *or*. I think there should be some other circumstances in which this rule should be applied, but it's still hard for us to identify. That's the very reason why I asked here originally. Thanks again for trying to get this clear!

Comment: @dan Yes, indeed there are several "rules of thumb" which are dependent on context. I have had a chat conversation with two native speakers and got more explanations about the usage of different negations ("and"/"or"). I will summarize them in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The verb will in fact dictate whether you'll use **and** or **or**, sometimes using  **and** and **or** in the same sentence, depending whether the elements are to be added, subtracted, or a divided in the action.

Am I a cat **or** a rabbit?

I can't be both a cat **and** a rabbit at the same time.

I am **not** a cat, **nor** **am I** a rabbit, **since** I bark to speak.

Someone asked me: " Do you like raw fish **or** carrots tips? I cooked a special dish for dogs, using both ingredients, **and** although it sounds like it, this dish was 
**not** made for cats **nor** **was it** for rabbits, **or** it would smell like it."

Someone asked me if I would rather eat raw fish **over**  carrots tips.

**Which** do you like better? Is it raw fish **or** carrot tips?

**Is** raw fish **or** carrots tips your favorite?

Are raw fish **and** carrots tips always **combined** in your food?

I eat fish **and** carrot tips. I am **not** a person **nor** am I a thing.

I am a pet **and** the best companion you'll ever get.

I want a pet **or** nothing.

I want a pet **and** nothing else.

I love my pet **and** no one else.

A carrot tip is the tip of a carrot, which is healthy for cats, dogs **and** of course, rabbits.