# "Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like them." how to say?

Tags: negation

"Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like them."

One way to express this meaning is

> I (don't) like **neither** bread **nor** rice **nor** porridge.

But this way is a little emphatic.

Are there another ways to express the same meaning without to put so much emphasis into the negation?

Comment: I think, ***Bread, rice and porridge - I don't like them.*** is the simplest you can get.

Comment: **[Similar Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103148/is-more-than-one-nor-after-a-neither-correct)** in _ELU_.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation may [resume in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69407/discussion-on-question-by-min-soo-pipefeet-bread-rice-and-porridge-i-dont-l).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conventional way to say this would be, "I don't like bread, rice, or porridge."

"Neither/nor" is normally used only when there are two things under discussion, and when we are contrasting them. Like, "He wanted to neither sit nor stand." It's awkward when there are more than two things, and not generally use when they are in the same "category".

Also, you shouldn't say "I don't like neither ..." This is a double negative and redundant. You can say "I like neither X nor Y" or "I don't like either X or Y".

What's wrong with simply, "I don't like ..."? If you're trying to sound less negative, to make it a weaker negative, then as Phil suggests, you could add a qualifying word, like "I don't particularly like ..." or "I don't really like ..." But note a curious English idiom here: "I don't really like X" means I dislike it a small amount. "I really don't like X" means I dislike it a lot.

- Very Late Addition in response to a comment *

RE '"I don't like bread, rice, or porridge". Isn't the meaning of it that I don't like at least one of them but not necessarily all of them?'

In a computer program or a mathematical theorem, it might mean that. But not in ordinary English. Yes, in boolean logic "if A or B" is true when A is true or B is true. But that's now how it works in plain English. Occasionally someone in a field that works with boolean logic will make a joke like this. Someone asks, "Are you coming on Tuesday or Wednesday?" and they say "Yes" and smile smugly, meaning that it is true that they are coming on Tuesday, or it is true that they are coming on Wednesday. What the person asking the question means, of course, is on which of the two days are you coming. A responsive answer would be "I am coming on Tuesday", or "I am coming on Wednesday", not "Yes" if you are coming on one of those days and "no" if you are not. (The fact that programmers and mathematicians think this kind of joke is hysterically funny probably says something about us, but that's another story.)

In ordinary English, if you say, "I don't like bread, rice, or porridge", you mean that you don't like any of the three.

If someone is asking a question, "Do you like bread, rice, or porridge?", it can be ambiguous. It can mean, "which of the three do you like?" or it can mean "do you like any of the three?". If the waiter asks, "Would you like soup or salad?", he probably means "which of the two".

Comment: The simply one is not wrong for me. I'm just in doubt about the meaning of *"I don't like bread, rice, or porridge"*. Isn't the meaning of it that I don't like *at least one of them* but not necessarily *all of them*? (Regarding "a double negative and redundant." - I agree. But nevertheless it's colloquial in American English, isn't it?)

Comment: Does the sentence *"I don't like bread, rice, **and** porridge"* have a different meaning than *"I don't like bread, rice, **or** porridge"*?

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet - Really, it's said well in this answer: _The conventional way to say this would be, "I don't like bread, rice, or porridge."_

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet In this context, using "and" instead of "or" would probably be understood to mean the same thing. But in other contexts it could be understood to mean that you don't like the combination. Like if someone said, "I don't like peanut butter and jelly", I'd take that to mean that he doesn't like the combination, but he might like peanut butter by itself or with other things, or he might like jelly with other things.

Comment: @Jay, will "I don't like peanut butter or jelly" make you think 'I don't like peanut and I don't like jelly'? Or it has to be "I don't like peanut either butter or jelly"?

Comment: @dan "Peanut butter" is one thing, "Jelly" is another. "Peanut butter" is basically just peanuts run through a blender or food processor until they're creamy. So you wouldn't say "I don't like peanut either butter or jelly." That would only make sense if there was such a thing as "peanut jelly", which I don't think exists. But if you had something like that, like "grape jelly" and "grape juice", you would normally give the full name of each, like, "I don't like either grape jelly or grape juice." ...

Comment: ... To pull the "grape" out you'd have to add extra words, like, "I don't like grapes, either as jelly or as juice". To just say, "I don't like grape either jelly or juice" would be confusing at best, not something a fluent speaker would say.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't like bread, rice, or porridge.
>
> I don't like bread and rice, or porridge for that matter.
>
> Bread, rice, porridge—I don't really care for any of them.

Comment: Isn't the meaning of *"I don't like bread, rice, or porridge"* that I don't like *at least one of them* but not necessarily *all of them*?

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet - People talking around the dinner table don't speak in cryptic logic, unless they are playing a riddle game. If Tᴚoɯɐuo said, "I don't like bread, rice, or porridge," most would (correctly) assume the dislike extends to all three.

Comment: My dislike applies to all members of the set: `{bread, rice, porridge}`.

Comment: @J.R. and Tᴚoɯɐuo: Is it also idiomatic to say (1) "I like no bread, no rice, and no porridge" or (2) "I like none of bread, rice, and porridge"?

Comment: @Min-Soo - In that comment, your second one is clunky, awkward, and non-idiomatic. The first one isn't as bad, but it changes the meaning of what you are trying to say. "I like no bread" means "I don't like any kind of bread."

Comment: @J.R. Great! You answer uncovered a difference to me I was completely unaware ("bread" vs. "any kind of bread") and do not understand yet; so probably it will become an own question. Just a last one for the current question: wouldn't the sentence *"I don't like bread, rice, **and** porridge"* be even less riddle game? Or does the *and* add a different meaning in this case?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Your second example sentence contains an *and*. Is the sentence "I don't like bread, rice, *and* porridge" possible too? Or does the *and* add a different meaning?

Comment: @Min-Soo Pipefeet: It would be understood to mean "I don't like bread and I don't like rice"; it could mean "I don't like bread mixed with rice" (if such a combination existed; context would clear up the ambiguity).

Comment: "I like none of {x, y, z}" is not idiomatic. "I like none of **those**" is idiomatic.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I am very curious what would be the difference between "I don't like bread, rice, **and** porridge" and "I don't like bread, rice, **or** porridge"

Comment: I doubt there is a pragmatic difference. With **and** there is a slight indication that the list is complete, as is. With **or**, there is a slight indication that the list could go on to include other items.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, so both are idiomatic, natural or common?

Answer (score 1):

Either "really" or "particularly" could be added to reduce the emphatic nature of "don't like".

Examples:
"I don't **really** like them".
"I don't **particularly** like them".