# "I don't like bread" vs. "I like no bread"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In [a comment to another question/answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148497/bread-rice-and-porridge-i-dont-like-them-how-to-say/148509?noredirect=1#comment300960_148509) I've been said that *"I like no bread"* means *"I don't like any kind of bread"* and is different in meaning from *"I don't like bread"*.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the difference in meaning between the two sencences.
Could you please explain?

Answer (score 3):

> *"I like no bread."*

Like saying "*I like no one*", this simply means that the speaker doesn't like any kind/ type of bread, and he dislikes bread, in all its variants. If you really think about it, it doesn't have a very different meaning from '*I don't like bread*.'

However, "*I don't like bread*" is a more generalized statement, when compared to the "*I like no bread*".

But the former can also mean that the speaker isn't fond of bread, but may like a particular type of bread. This is only valid when "*I don't like bread*" is a part of whole sentence. Consider the following sentence:

> *"I don't like bread, but I like the ones you make."*

This means that the speaker has a general dislike for bread, but likes a particular bread, made by the listener. But if he had said "*I like no bread*", then it clearly means that he likes none of the variants of bread, irrespective of type, shape or flavor.